# Getting 400 Bad Request error when sending form data Angular

Tags: angularjs, multipartform-data, http-status-code-400

I am getting a 400 Error when sending a form data to my node.js backend. It also gives me this error: `Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0` I know that it isn't a problem with my node app because I can send the same data using Postman and it works perfectly.

This is my Angular method:

```
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("db", $scope.item.db.toLowerCase());
      formData.append(
        "collection",
        $("#collection")
          .find("option:selected")
          .text()
          .toLowerCase()
      );
      formData.append("owner", JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user"))._id);
      formData.append("name", $scope.item.name);
      formData.append("description", $scope.item.description);
      formData.append("year", $scope.item.year);
      formData.append("photo", $("#picture")[0].files[0]);
      $http.post("items/uploadItem", formData).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
      });
    };
```

If you need any more information, please leave a comment and I would be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was still sending the data as a json doc. The trick was to change the http call to this:

```
$http.post("items/uploadItem", formData, {headers: { "Content-Type": undefined }})
```

Answer (score 0):

The Angular $http service is expecting standard objects, not a form object. You are sending a serialised form object to your end point. Try

```
const formData = {
  db: $scope.item.db.toLowerCase(),
  // and the rest of your object properties. 
};
```